# Google SpreadSheet custom range

Tags: google-sheets

I have to copy data from spreadhSheet A Column `A3:Infinity` to spreadhSheet B Column A `A253:Infinity`. How I can specify `Infinity` OR `endOfColumn` in range, while there will also be empty rows between A3,Infinity and A253, Infinity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spreadsheet B, cell A253, write:

```
= IMPORTRANGE(<<key_of_spreadsheet_A>>; "<sheet_name>!A3:A")
```

where "key_of_spreadsheet_A" is the key of Spreadsheet A (you can find it in the URL), and "sheet name" is the name of the sheet in spreadsheet A from which you want to import.